# why is attr() applying only last one style?

Tags: jquery

i want to know that why attr() is applying last one style attribute only i would like  to know in detail what will be reason?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <p id="prg1">first paragraph</p>
</body>

<script src="C:\Users\SUDARSHAN\Desktop\html_UI\jquery-3.6.0.js">
</script>
<script>
   $('document').ready(function (){

      $('#prg1').attr({style:'color:yellow',style:'font-family:arial',style:'color:yellow',style:'border-style:dotted'});
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Objects in JS cannot have repeating keys. So if you do `{foo: 1, foo: 2, foo: 3}` that just resolves to `{ foo: 3 }`

Comment: it means it will always apply last one style attribute if it is same  am i right?

Comment: `.attr` sets the attribute each time, it doesn't not append to an existing property. So the last one "wins".

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you looking for

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <p id="prg1">first paragraph</p>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
   $('document').ready(function(){$('#prg1').css({color:'yellow','font-family':'arial','color':'yellow','border-style':'dotted'});})
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery for this at all? By putting the style declaration in the js, you will get a flash of the unstyled content untill jquery loads and gets to the ready() state and then on document.ready()  -the js will be applied and change the styles - why not simply use CSS to do what it is supposed to do - provide the styling for the html elements?

```css
#prg1 {
  color:yellow;
  font-family: "arial";
  border: 1px dotted red;
 )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <p id="prg1">first paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```