# If there is duplicate attribute in the attr() then does it always apply last one duplicate attribute in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am very confused only i want to know if i gave duplicate attribute in attr() then can i only apply last one attribute ex --> `attr({style:'color:yellow',style:'font-family:arial',style:'color:yellow'})` I I have given three same style here can only apply last one? Is it possible to apply second one style?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <p id="prg1">first paragraph</p>
</body>
<script src="C:\Users\SUDARSHAN\Desktop\html_UI\jquery-3.6.0.js">
</script>
<script>
   $('document').ready(function (){

      $('#prg1').attr({style:'color:yellow',style:'font-family:arial',style:'color:yellow',style:'border-style:dotted'});
    
   })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: [As before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961404/why-is-attr-applying-only-last-one-style#comment123670815_69961404) you cannot have duplicate keys in an object. It's nothing specific with jQuery - the object you create only ever has a single property. If you want that property to be different, *don't overwrite it*.

Comment: but will it always apply last one duplicate key?

Comment: `.attr` sets the attribute each time, it doesn't not append to an existing property. So the last one "wins".

Answer (score 1):

So, your question is a little bit confusing, but I will try to address all possible scenarios:

1. Your code has a very bad error: you cannot have duplicate keys in objects, regardless of this being a style or a `.attr()` function. So this is completely wrong;
   any object `b = { a: 1, a: 2 }` is ***invalid*** and should not be used but the result will be `b === { a: 2 }`
2. If you try to use `.attr({style:'color:yellow'}).attr({style:'font-family:arial')` yes, it will get the last one since the `attr` function always overwrite the value, never merges it;
3. I think this is what you really want to know how to do: `.attr({ style:'color:yellow; font-family:arial; border-style:dotted'});` see that every item on the style is separated by ';'.
   Basically, when you use `.attr` + style you are setting the complete style attribute for the html element, which means a whole css code so you don't need neither one 'style' per prop nor one 'attr' per prop;
   Simply set the entire css string to the style attribute, that said, you can have as many css props you want, just split them with ';'

---

EDIT: I've answered here based on your question, but as @Phil mentioned on the first comment below, you might get a better solution by using the [.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) from jquery:

```
.css({
    color: "yellow", fontFamily: "arial", borderStyle: "dotted"
  });
```

Note the use of camelCase for the props with "-", or instead put the entire prop name among quotes like "border-style"

:)

Comment: The [.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method seems a better fit for setting multiple `style` properties at once