# Why does attr() apply last one duplicate style if i gave it multiple style there in attr() method in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have used **attr()** for applying style on element and I have given 4 style attribute but it is applying last one style attribute so I want to know why it is applying last one style  only,  what is the reason?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <p id="prg1">first paragraph</p>
   <h1 id="h11">first heading</h1>
   <h1 id="h22">second heading</h1>
</body>
<script src="C:\Users\SUDARSHAN\Desktop\html_UI\jquery-3.6.0.js">
</script>
<script>
   $('document').ready(function (){
      $('#prg1').attr({style:'color:yellow',style:' font-family:arial',style: 'border-style:dotted'})
   })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69961404) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69962448)

Comment: Don't make new users to post the same answer again and again. This will not improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Is this a homework question?   Might explain the duplicate question from different users (giving the benefit of doubt), Homework questions are allowed, but you're supposed to do *some* research yourself first.

Comment: `.attr` *sets* the attribute each time, it doesn't not append to an existing property.  So the last one "wins".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you want to apply multiple options in the style:

```
$('#prg1').attr({
  style: 'color:yellow;font-family:arial;border-style:dotted'
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#prg1').attr({
    style: 'color:yellow;font-family:arial;border-style:dotted'
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="prg1">first paragraph</p>
<h1 id="h11">first heading</h1>
<h1 id="h22">second heading</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#prg1').css({'color:yellow;font-family:arial;border-style:dotted'})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="prg1">first paragraph</p>
<h1 id="h11">first heading</h1>
<h1 id="h22">second heading</h1>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well done for adding a snippet, but did you even run your own snippet?  That's not how you use the `.css` method.